# multi-panel plots in ggplot2: scales that are "free and equal"?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have issued the following command to a ggplot figure:

```
facet_wrap(~variable,scales="free")
```

but I also want for the x and y scales to be equal for each panel (while the limits vary from panel to panel). Is this possible in ggplot2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `facet_grid`, you can specify `space='free'`. I think this is what you want.

```
require(ggplot2)

x = 1:9
group = rep(1:3, each=3)
data = data.frame(x, group)
qplot(x, x, data=data) + facet_grid(~group, scales='free', space='free')
```

Comment: Thanks, but this actually this sets all y-axes limits to (1,9) and the x-axis intervals to 3 (with different limits for each panel). How can I set x and y-axis limits in panel 1 to (1,9) and (1,9), respectively, and in panel 2 to (1,3) and (1,3), respectively, and so on?

Comment: With facet_grid, the x-axis for all facets in the same column must be the same, and, likewise, the y-axis for all facets in the same row must be the same. Check out the examples at http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/facet_grid.html and http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/facet_wrap.html, but it sounds like you might be hitting a limitation of ggplot2 here.