# Free scale, but same per-panel range in x/y

Tags: r, ggplot2

I try to get free scaling with aspect=1, but same range in x/y in each panel. In the example below, this means that x-scaling in b should be (-0.04,0.04).

Edited: added lattice version

```
library(ggplot2)
d = data.frame(x=rnorm(100),group=c("A","B"))
d$y = d$x+rnorm(100,0,0.5)
d[d$group=="B","x"]=d[d$group=="B","x"]/100
d[d$group=="B","y"]=d[d$group=="B","y"]/60
qplot(x,y,data=d,asp=1) + facet_wrap(~group,scale="free")

require(lattice)
xyplot(y~x|group, data=d,aspect=1,scales=list(relation="free"),
   prepanel=function(x,y){
     lims = c(min(x,y), max(x,y))
     list(xlim=lims,ylim=lims)
   } )
```

[image: in each panel, the x and y range should be the same]

Comment: +1 Good question. I fiddled around, but couldn't get it to work as you request.

Comment: @Andrie: As a died-in-the wool latticist, I first thought it was just my partisan ignorance. After your comment, I found a thread [https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/ggplot2/cDzL_yHew0I[1-25] ] indicating that this is not that easy in ggplot2.

Comment: Looks like I missed that negative one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905828/multi-panel-plots-in-ggplot2-scales-that-are-free-and-equal?rq=1

Comment: In principle, you want `facet_wrap(~group, scale="free")` and `coord_equal(ratio=1)`, but 1) These two don't work together and 2) `coord_equal` makes the spacing along the axes the same (1 unit along the axis is the same length), but does not (have an option to) fix the coordinate limits to the same values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the latest version of `ggplot2` uses `gtable` internally, you can do this kind of task quite easily:

```
d = data.frame(x=rnorm(100),group=c("A","B"))
d$y = d$x+rnorm(100,0,0.5)
d[d$group=="B","x"]=d[d$group=="B","x"]/100
d[d$group=="B","y"]=d[d$group=="B","y"]/60

# create plots for each level of group
p <- lapply(levels(d$group), 
  function(i) {
    dat <- subset(d, group == i)
    lim <- range(c(dat$x, dat$y))
    ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(qplot(x,y,data=dat,asp=1) + 
      facet_wrap(~group,scale="free") + 
      coord_equal() +
      xlim(lim) + ylim(lim)))
    })

# tweaking margins
p[[1]] <- p[[1]][, -6]
p[[2]] <- p[[2]][, -(1:2)]

# draw it
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(cbind(p[[1]], p[[2]], size = "first"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @kohske, but the lattice solution using prepanel seems to be much more streamlined to me.

Comment: +1, although I have to agree with Dieter, ggplot's strength is normally the fact that there no need for lowlevel details.